# Página JSF exibindo valor de referência do Objeto

Tags: ajax, jsf, java-ee, primefaces, xhtml

boa noite.

Tenho uma página em JSF chamada simulado.xhtml no qual **implemento um filtro para gerar o simulado e também estou tentando exibir resultados do banco de dados que já foram filtrados nessa mesma página**, porém como resultado obtenho esses resultados:

**[com.sisEnade.tcc.modelo.Questao@20, com.sisEnade.tcc.modelo.Questao@21, com.sisEnade.tcc.modelo.Questao@22]**

Tentei implementar em um dataTable mais sempre que clico no gerar Simulado eu recebo um notFound, é como se o dataTable precisasse recarregar logo depois de clicar no botão. Podem me ajudar com esse detalhe também?

Estou tentando exibir da seguinte maneira para testar:

Página JSF:

```
    <ui:define name="titulo">Gerar Simulado</ui:define>

    <ui:define name="corpo">

        <h1>Filtro para gerar Simulado</h1>
        <h:form id="frmCadastro">
            <br></br>

            <h:panelGrid columns="2">

                <p:outputLabel value="Curso" for="curso" style="font-weight:bold" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="curso"
                    value="#{gerarSimuladoBean.cursoSelecionado}"
                    converter="cursoConverter" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Preencha o curso">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione..." />
                    <f:attribute name="collectionType" value="java.util.ArrayList" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroQuestaoBean.cursos}" var="curso"
                        itemLabel="#{curso.nome}" itemValue="#{curso}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>


            <h:panelGrid id="gridComplexidade" columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel value="Complexidade da Questão" for="complexidade"
                    style="font-weight:bold" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="complexidade"
                    value="#{gerarSimuladoBean.complexidadeSelecionada}"
                    required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Por favor, preencha a complexidade.">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione..." />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="4" itemValue="4" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="5" itemValue="5" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid id="gridNumeroQuestoes" columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel value="Número de questoes" for="numeroDeQuestoes"
                    style="font-weight:bold" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="numeroDeQuestoes"
                    value="#{gerarSimuladoBean.numeroDeQuestoesSimulado}"
                    required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Por favor, preencha o numero de questoes.">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione..." />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="5" itemValue="5" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="10" itemValue="10" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="20" itemValue="20" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="40" itemValue="40" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>

            <p:commandButton value="Gerar Simulado"
                action="#{gerarSimuladoBean.gerarSimulado}" icon="ui-icon-search"
                iconPos="right" update="frmCadastro">
            </p:commandButton>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <p:panelGrid id="teste">
                <h:outputText value="#{gerarSimuladoBean.questoes}">
                </h:outputText>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Trecho aonde está exibindo os endereços dos objetos:

```
<p:panelGrid id="teste">
                    <h:outputText value="#{gerarSimuladoBean.questoes}">
                    </h:outputText>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tal valor aparece porque você está mandando imprimir o objeto da lista aqui:

```
<h:outputText value="#{gerarSimuladoBean.questoes}">
```

Se o valor passado para a tag `<h:outputText>` não for uma `String`, o método `toString()` do objeto será chamado para se obter a representação textual do mesmo.

O problema não ocorreria com o componente `<dataTable>` porque ele daria conta de exibir cada item da lista adequadamente, mas para que funcione você realmente precisa instruir a tabela a se atualizar quando se clica no botão.

A atualização já deveria ocorrer pois você usou o atributo `update` no botão.

Não entendi bem o que quis dizer com "notFound". Se o método do botão realmente existe não deveria ocorrer tal erro. Cuidado se você estiver fazendo algum redirecionamento para um local não existente, mas isso não deveria ocorrer, pois a atualização dos componentes no PrimeFaces é feita via Ajax.

Este é toda a ajuda que posso dar com as informações disponíveis.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, resolveu perfeitamente. Entretanto, estou com um outro problema. Postei mais abaixo como resposta, por favor pode me ajudar?

Comment: @FelipePortela Não entendi bem o que quis dizer com "console do dataTable". Se você está exibindo os textos um após o outro numa página web, eles não vão respeitar quebras de linha no código da página. Para quebrar linhas em HTML você pode usar  as tags `<br/>`, `<p>` ou, melhor ainda nesse contexto, lista não ordnadas com `<ul>` e `<li>`.